# Why does R sometimes stop displaying output?

Tags: r

Sometimes R stops displaying output. I type the number 1, followed by the return key, and nothing appears.

This situation occurred after I pressed the "STOP" icon in the window, which is for stopping long calculations. I'm using R 2.11.0 on a Mac.

Does pressing "STOP" cause R to stop displaying output? How do I get R to display output again?

Comment: I found out that "STOP" does not always cause R to stop displaying output. But when R does stop displaying output, I don't know how to get it to display output again.

Comment: Maybe you got `sink()` somewhere in code and when you stop calculation sinking is not ended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you running a Sweave script or something else with output redirection? Breaking out of a Sweave script will frequently leave you with no output. Try `sink(NULL)` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After reading it, I ran brew twice, stopping it before finished (brew, like Sweave, is a package for report generation). I used sink(NULL), and the output came back. Possibly I was using brew when I had my original output problems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might get some/better help by asking this question on the R-sig-mac mailing list. You can subscribe to it here: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac

Comment: I have seen this on Windows as well, so I don't think this is Mac-specific.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. By Aniko's comment, maybe this issue is not Mac-specific. I joined the "r-help" list, instead of the "r-sig-mac" list.