# Why does RStudio not give output?

Tags: r

I'm new to R and recently I'm facing a weird problem.

When I open a new R session, everything works fine.. but after some time some commands stop working. when I execute that command:

```
getwd()
```

the output is just:

```
> getwd()
```

Instead of displaying my working directory it just displays the executed command.

After working with the session for a while, the output of variables also stops displaying. I have to close the entire Rstudio and open it anew to rectify this problem. This is wasting a lot of time.

How to come out of this??

Comment: This sounds like you are running out of memory and the application is behaving strangely.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Any suggestions about what can be done?? The system space seems to be very fine.. No memory running out in my computer.

Comment: Type `memory.limit()` to see how much memory R has available.

Comment: Maybe relevant [Why does R sometimes stop displaying output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924334/why-does-r-sometimes-stop-displaying-output)

Comment: May I suggest retitling "Why does **RStudio** not give output?  Unless you can reproduce this behavior with `R` from the command line or the Rgui, it's probably an RStudio problem.  What computer and what OS are you using?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thanks for the suggestion.. Made the suggested change in the question. And my OS is Windows 7 (64bit desktop computer)